# How does lockscreen affect to an app?

Tags: android, locking, screen, keypress

I am creating an app which needs to listen to a (hardware) keypress during a long time period so, I thought that if I lock the screen during that period the phone would save a lot of battery. But some months ago I read something about androids lockscreen.. It was said that during lockscreen, the phone would not be able to listen to hardware keypresses...  Am  I right?

After this explanation, my question is: Does anyone know any way of listening to a keypress with locked screen in order to not drain a lot of battery?

I thought something about putting screen brightness to its lowest value, but Cpu will be draining battery, because phone is not in deep sleep, so I think this is not the correct way :)

any other way, please???

Thanks in advance!!! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to start an infinitely running service to achieve what you are trying to do.
I would like to suggest you a more efficient way to do this, which is making use of [ACTION_SCREEN_OFF](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) instead. Good Luck.

Comment: yes, you could save your battery by turning off the display rather than making the phone go into a sleep state. How does that sound?

Comment: but i think turning off the screen is not the same as making it sleep... am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WakeLock feature to save battery.
Refer to this [link](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/02/07/android-wakelock/)

Comment: will I be able to listen for keypresses using wakelock?